# 2-D Arrays and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, array-formulas, pointer-arithmetic

I was taught that a compiler converts an array name to a pointer to array's 1st element whenever necessary. So I used this rule to solve many problems and it was all fine till I saw this.

```
int main()
{
    int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {5,6,7}}, (*p)[3];
    p = a[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d", (*p)[i]);
}
```

Output was `123` with code blocks.

I tried to solve it as :

`(*p)[i])` should be same as `*((*p)+i)`....(1)

As rule said, **"Array name is converted to a pointer to array's 1st element".** I converted 2nd instruction `p=a[0]` to `p=&a[0][0]` *(because `a[0]` is a sub-array name whose 1st element is `a[0][0]`).* So `(*p)` can be written as `(*(&a[0][0]))`. Which is same as `a[0][0]`. So eqn (1) becomes

```
*(a[0][0]+i).
```

And here's where I am stuck. `a[0][0]+i` is an element and not an address. So applying `*` operator to it is invalid. But I have also replaced statement `p=a[0];` with `p=&a[0][0];` in original code, answer remains same. Also I replaced it with `p=&a[0];`. Answer still remains same. And now I am super confused.

Comment: If you compile the program you'll **have** to get something like **warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 p=a[0] ;**, which explains why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You were taught correctly [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) --- your implementation is just wrong, instead `p=a;`. Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang) and (`/W3` for VS) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. `a[0]` is `int *`, however `p` is `int (*)[3]`. Since  `a` will decay to a pointer to the first element on access (that being an array of 3 int), `a` is compatible with `p`, not `a[0]`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes it generated warning. But why this is not an compilation error? Does that mean that compiler already converted it into compatible type by itself?. And if this code is given to me in a written exam, should I mark error as my correct option?

Comment: It is not a compilation error because [the C standard explicitly allows a compiler to successfully compile an **invalid program**, provided that required diagnostics are issued](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note9). This is to allow a C compiler to be used to compile all sorts of b0rken code from the 1970s and so...

Comment: So should I say that above code is a faulty code and right one will be if I write `p=&a[0]` or `p=a` instead of `p=a[0]`.

Comment: Yes, but `&a[0]` is a superfluous use of `&` since `&a[0]` is `&*(a + 0)` or just `(a + 0)` or simply `a`.

Comment: It is fine, it is just superfluous. `&a[0] = &(*(a + 0))` (taking `&` of `*` simply cancels) meaning  `&(*(a + 0)) = (a + 0)` which is just `a`. You can use either (they are the same so the *types* are equivalent).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Hey thanks, I am all clear now.

Comment: Awesome, learning has occurred -- that makes it a good day....

Answer (score 0):

2D arrays are  *Array of 1D Arrays*

In 1d arrays,

```
a[0] => *(a)     -> first element of array
a[1] => *(a + 1) -> second element of array
```

in 2d arrays,

```
a => the adress of first array
a[0] => *(a)        -> the first array 
a[0][0] => *(*(a))     -> the first element of first array
a[0][1] => *(*(a) + 1) -> second element of first array
a[1][1] => *(*(a + 1) + 1) -> second element of second array
```

Comment: Not quite. `a[2][3]` decays to `(*a)[3]` on access (*pointer to int [3]*), `a[0]` (which is *int [3]*) decays to `int *` on access (*pointer to int*). [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: To clarify, your pointer/index equivalents are correct (though missing a closing paren on the next to last), the problem is `"2d arrays are array of pointer of pointers."`. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays, they are separate and distinct types even though an array will be converted to a pointer to it's first element on access.

Comment: yes, sorry for wrong information. probably the most correct definition is like `2d arrays are array of pointer of arrays.` because they are not consecutive elements at the memory. if i'm wrong can you correct me please

Comment: No problem, no ding for it, I knew what you intended, but somebody new or struggling with the concept won't. Best to tidy up the language a bit. And technically a 2D array is an *Array of 1D Arrays*, the pointers only come into the picture with the application of Section 6.3.2.1.

Comment: @1v3m: No “2d arrays are array of pointers of arrays” is not a correct definition. `int a[2][3]` is an array of 2 arrays of 3 `int`, and all the elements are consecutive. There are no pointers involved.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
p = a[0];
```

The type of `p` is pointer to array of 3 `int`. The type of `a[0]` is pointer to `int`. Your compiler should have given you a warning for this. If it did not, enable whatever switch(es) are necessary to turn on most or all of your compiler warnings. When the compiler issues a warning, do not ignore it—make sure you understand why the compiler is issuing a warning before you proceed. It would be a good idea to enable a compiler feature that turns warnings into errors.

A correct statement would be `p = a;` or `p = &a[0];`. But let’s examine what did happen in your program. In the expression `a[0]`:

- By definition of the subscript operator, `a[0]` is equivalent to `*(a+0)` (technically `(*((a)+(0)))`, but we do not need the extra parentheses in this case).
- `a` is an array, so it is converted to a pointer to its first element. So `a` is converted to a pointer to `a[0]`. So the expression is now `*(&a[0] + 0)`.
- Adding `0` to `&a[0]` does not change it, so the result is `&a[0]`, and the expression is now `*&a[0]`.
- Applying `*` to a pointer yields the thing that is pointed to, so the expression becomes `a[0]`.
- `a[0]` is an array of 3 `int`. Since it is an array, it is converted to a pointer to its first element. So the result is effectively `&a[0][0]`.

Observe that `&a[0][0]` is a pointer to an `int`, as I wrote above. So now we see that `p = a[0];` has a pointer to an `int` on the right side but a pointer to an array of 3 `int` on the left. This violates a constraint in the C standard, and a compiler **must** issue a diagnostic message for it.

After the warning, what your compiler likely did was convert the pointer, resulting in `p` being set to point to `a[0]`.

> I converted 2nd instruction `p=a[0]` to `p=&a[0][0]` (*because `a[0]` is a sub-array name whose 1st element is `a[0][0]`*). So `(*p)` can be written as `(*(&a[0][0]))`.

This is a mistake. Although you executed the assignment `p = a[0]`, this did not assign `&a[0][0]` to `p`, and `p` does not behave as if it were `&a[0][0]`. The assignment **converted** `&a[0][0]` to the type of `p`. `p` remains the type it was declared to be, a pointer to an array of 3 `int`. In effect, `p` ends up with the value of `&a[0]`.

Now we can evaluate `(*p)[i]`:

- `p` is `&a[0]`, so the expression becomes `(*&a[0])[i])`.
- `*&a[0]` is `a[0]`, so the expression becomes `a[0][i]`.
- From there, we can proceed with the usual expression evaluation, and it is clear the result is element `i` of element 0 of `a`.